One Java function fails to activate after another begins
I am very new to coding. I am trying to create a series of maps of Hawai'i, where the political borders change as you select buttons with dates. I am doing this by using javascript to change the image source and css styles of a specific nation's border. Currently, I can select the 1782 button, and that will work; then I will select the 1810 button, and that will work; but if I try to return to the 1782 button, nothing will happen.
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSSHawai'iHistory.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <!--have a series of dates to click through-->
        <div id="Dates">
            <button id="hawaii1782" type="clickable-button">1782</button>
            <button id="hawaii1810" type="clickable-button">1810</button>    
        </div>  
        <br>
        <!--Image of Kamehameha's land-->
        <img id="Nation" src="https://i.postimg.cc/J0J0yS3R/Waipi-o.png">
        <script src="SCRIPTHawai'iHistory.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
Java:
    const hawaii1782 = document.querySelector("#hawaii1782");
    const hawaii1810 = document.querySelector("#hawaii1810");
    const Nation = document.querySelector("#Nation")
    var r = document.querySelector(':root');

    hawaii1782.onclick = map1782;
    hawaii1810.onclick = map1810;

    //have 1782 button go to map in 1782
    function map1782(){
        Nation.src="https://i.postimg.cc/J0J0yS3R/Waipi-o.png";
        r.style.setProperty('--country-size','89px');
        r.style.setProperty('--east-margin','879px');
        r.style.setProperty('--north-margin','360px');
        r.style.setProperty('--border1782','red');
        r.style.setProperty('--border1810','#feac32');
        hawaii1810.onclick = map1810;
   }

    //have 1810 map go to map in 1810
    function map1810(){
        Nation.src="https://i.postimg.cc/cLrmrH39/Kingdom-Hawai-i.png";
        r.style.setProperty('--country-size', '1150px');
        r.style.setProperty('--east-margin','-10px');
        r.style.setProperty('--north-margin','-49px');
        r.style.setProperty('--border1782','#feac32')
        r.style.setProperty('--border1810','red');
        hawaii1782.onclick = map1782;
   }
CSS:
    /*variables*/
    :root {
        --country-size: 89px;
        --east-margin: 879px;
        --north-margin: 360px;
        --border1782: #feac32;
        --border1810: #feac32;
        } 
    body {
            background-image:url("https://i.postimg.cc/d1tBvjYs/Blank.png");
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }


    /*Kamehameha's land*/
    #Nation {
        width: var(--country-size);    
        margin-left: var(--east-margin); 
        margin-top: var(--north-margin);
        background-color:transparent;
        }

    /*1782 button*/
    #hawaii1782{
        background-color: #feac32;
        color: #0a0a23;
        border: 3px solid var(--border1782);
        background-image:linear-gradient(#fecc4c, #ffac33);
    
        }

     /*1810 button*/
    #hawaii1810{
       background-color: #feac32;
       color: #0a0a23;
       border: 3px solid var(--border1810);
       background-image:linear-gradient(#fecc4c, #ffac33);
      }

I figured the issue was caused by the 1810 function not finishing. However, the 1810 script is almost identical to the 1782 script, and if I initiate the 1782 function, I can still initiate the 1810 function.

just as a note, JavaScript is not Java

The problem is that when you click the 1810 button, you place the invisible part of a image above your buttons. This makes it seem like you can't click on the buttons, when really there is just something in the way.
To solve this problem, move the  <img id="Nation" src="https://i.postimg.cc/J0J0yS3R/Waipi-o.png"> element before the  <div id="Dates"> element in your html code. This will place the buttons below the images. When you click on either button, the image will change but they will not be blocked.
This resolves the problem with the buttons clicking, but now your buttons are on the bottom of the page and move when you change the image. If you want to keep the buttons on the top of the page, I would recommend changing the buttons to being in a floating div, something you can learn about here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.php.
